# Intermittent 4xx errors with soundcloud API

Tags: soundcloud

I have a shell script that uploads an audio file to a SoundCloud account via `curl`. Recently it started misbehaving. Specifically:

1. `/oauth2/token` intermittently returns a `401 Unauthorized` for the same request payload. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.
2. `/tracks.json` always returns `422 Unprocessable Entity`.

Here is the upload script:

```
#!/bin/bash

audio_path=/tmp/test.wav # RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz
sc_client_id=...
sc_client_secret=...
sc_username=...
sc_password=...
track_name=$(date +'%F-%H%M%S')

# Get SoundCloud auth token
auth_token=$(curl -sX POST 'https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token' \
    -F "client_id=${sc_client_id}" \
    -F "client_secret=${sc_client_secret}" \
    -F "grant_type=password" \
    -F "username=${sc_username}" \
    -F "password=${sc_password}" | \
    grep -Po '(?<="access_token":")[^"]+(?=")')
if [ -z "$auth_token" ]; then
    echo "Failed to get auth token from SoundCloud" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Upload audio to SoundCloud
curl --fail -sX POST 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json' \
    -F "oauth_token=${auth_token}" \
    -F "track[asset_data]=@${audio_path}" \
    -F "track[title]=${track_name}" \
    -F "track[sharing]=public" >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$audio_path -> $track_name"
else
    echo "Failed to upload audio to SoundCloud" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I looked for changes in the API docs[1] but nothing is jumping out at me. I'm curious if others can reproduce this issue or if it's something on my end. Any tips are much appreciated. Thanks!

[1] https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide